# creating log files for DB table entries using SSIS package

Tags: sql-server-2008, logging

I have an application that after doing parsing inserts records into a table. There are +- 30 million records a day and I usually send a report for daily totals at the end of the day. Now I am required to create log files every few minutes or seconds so that we can feed the counts of new records inserted into a realtime syslog type feed application that will display this data realtime. I am not sure if I should write to a text file each time I do an insert or should I create these log files from within sql server for that table. Can this even be done? I am worried about the overhead in writing to a file after each insert. Any advice appreciated.

EDIT:

I wanted to word the question a little differently. I already use a SSIS sql package to create log files once a day. Can I setup the queries to run every 30 minutes or so and collect all new records inserted since the last run?

I have 3/4 columns in the table one of which is used in the select, which is the dateAdded column and the records are grouped according to this column for daily reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you could solve the problem a little bit differently, it would be much more efficient.

In your application where you are parsing the records and inserting them into a table, you could add a few lines of code that increments a counter that represents the number of records inserted.

This counter could then be displayed in realtime on a desktop/smartphone web page to as many users as are interested in viewing the count.  Actually, a realtime graph of Count versus Time would be even more interesting.

What language is your application written in?  I may be able to dig up a simple realtime web demo app that increments a count in realtime using C/C++.